# Horizontal scrolling of genlist

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In case of a genlist, you can select from multiple modes via `elm_genlist_mode_set`.

Most of the samples are using `ELM_LIST_COMPRESS`.

I tried all the options, but I can't reach my goal on Tizen5 (wearable):

How can I have a genlist which is able to be panned horizontally in case of containing longer items? Or shall I put it into a scroller?

Answer (score 0):

ELM_LIST_SCROLL is the option to turn on the horizontal scroll, but it may not works in wearable item styles.

most of portable devices, scroller is limited one directions, so wearable item styles also designed to be fit on the screen.

To extend your item bigger as their text size, text(or textblock) part text.min need to be 1 on their width and ellipsis must be off.
so  you need to create your own customized item styles to do this.

many of your question and requirement need customized item styles. I hope you try to get the efl-theme-tizen-wearable in review.tizen.org. try another mail services or create another account on gmail.

Comment: Scroll works when I have a text which is longer than screen. And yes, I have a custom item style, and it offers a content part. Into that content I'm putting a label, and a *padding* rect. In case of this, scrolling is not working.

Comment: and regarding my registration trials (with another email address): https://imgur.com/a/rYdRw6A

Comment: that is more related with label is stretched properly...
but as you know,
mobile and wearable devices are not familiar with 2-axis scrolls.